# Construir uma nova Array com base em valores em comum PHP

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho um array com diversos valores distintos:

```
$data = [
    'ON' => [
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 115,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 1',
            'Pa_fk'          => 1,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 1'
        ],
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 115,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 2',
            'Pa_fk'          => 2,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 2'
        ],
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 115,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 3',
            'Pa_fk'          => 3,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 3'
        ],
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 116,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 1',
            'Pa_fk'          => 1,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 1'
        ],
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 116,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 2',
            'Pa_fk'          => 2,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 2'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Eu quero agrupar os dados em um novo array, usando a propriedade **`Pa_fk`** como grupador:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Indicador_fk] => 115
                    [Indicador_Nome] => Exemplo 1
                    [Pa_fk] => 1
                    [Pa_Nome] => Exemplo 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Indicador_fk] => 116
                    [Indicador_Nome] => Exemplo 1
                    [Pa_fk] => 1
                    [Pa_Nome] => Exemplo 1
                )

        )
```

O que eu tentei fazer foi:

```
$IndicadorAnterior = 999998;
$IndicadorAtual = 999999;

foreach ($datas['ON'] as $Linha) {
    $IndicadorAtual = $Linha->Indicador_fk;

    if ($IndicadorAtual != $IndicadorAnterior) {
        $PaAnterior = 9999999;
        $PaAtual = 99999998;

        foreach ($datas['ON'] as $Linha2) {
            $PaAtual = $Linha2->Pa_fk;

            if ($PaAtual != $PaAnterior) {
                $NovoArrayPA[$PaAtual] = $Linha2;
            }

            $PaAnterior = $PaAtual;
        }
    }

    $IndicadorAnterior = $IndicadorAtual;
}
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques Pergunta editada, conforme sugerido.

Comment: @AugustoVasques "Em geral quem ajuda aqui no site está trabalhando e usa os horários vagos para solucionar problemas dos outros. Se você não se der condições de ser ajudado ninguém vai o ajudar, vão negativar e fechar sua questão" Só dizendo isso você tambem não ajuda quem está começando, sugiro apontar como poderia ser mais claro em minha pergunta. Visto que estou começando no PHP agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ideia é apenas agrupar pela propriedade `Pa_fk`, uma maneira de você fazer, seria assim:

```
$data = [
    'ON' => [
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 115,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 1',
            'Pa_fk'          => 1,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 1'
        ],
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 115,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 2',
            'Pa_fk'          => 2,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 2'
        ],
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 115,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 3',
            'Pa_fk'          => 3,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 3'
        ],
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 116,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 1',
            'Pa_fk'          => 1,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 1'
        ],
        [
            'Indicador_fk'   => 116,
            'Indicador_Nome' => 'Exemplo 2',
            'Pa_fk'          => 2,
            'Pa_Nome'        => 'Exemplo 2'
        ]
    ]
];

$groupedByFk = [];

foreach ($data['ON'] as $item) {
    $groupedByFk[$item['Pa_fk']][] = $item;
}
```

O array `$groupedByFk` contém os arrays agrupados.

Você pode testar pelo [ideone](https://ideone.com/gkdSA6).

Comment: @GustavoFreze Obrigado, seu codigo sucinto resolveu meu problema.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Obrigado por ajudar na edição da pergunta.